# Infinite redirecting loop CoovaChilli

Tags: host, openwrt, coovachilli

I'm working with an accesspoint with OPENWRT and I want to redirect the hosts connected via Wifi to a concrete page. The problem is that when I turn on the browser appears infinite loop saying "redirecting", and this all the time.
I have tried to modify the chilli config file by adding:

```
HS_REDIRSSL=on
HS_SSLKEYFILE=/etc/chilli/key.pem
HS_SSLCERTFILE=/etc/chilli/cert.pem
```

but I'm still having the same problem. Could someone help me?

This is my html code to redirect the hosts:

```html
<html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://footanalytics.com/" />
</head>
                <body>
              <font size="3" face="verdana" color="black">
                   <i>REDIRECTING</i>
               </font>
       </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this, edit this file: /etc/config/coovachilli, at the end of this file:

```c
config general 'hotspot2'
    option mode 'norad'
    option net '192.168.3.254/24'
    option enabled '1'
    option externalpage '1'
    option uamlogoutip '1.1.1.1'
    option defidletimeout '600'
    option defsessiontimeout '600'
    option period '3'
    option day '1'
    option externadress 'http://example.com'
```

**enabled '1'** enables the wifi

**external page '1'** enables the option to redirect you to a requiered page when you connect to wifi

**externadress** defines the adrees where you want to be redirected

Don't touch the other options, they are configured by default.

bernat